# Send Events in JSON format via websockets

Tags: javascript, json, websocket, jasmine, dom-events

I am trying to form a JSON Response using jansson lib on the server side
and below is the code snippet to frame the JSON response to the request made by the client (written in js)

```
json_object_set(root,"response",msgType);
            json_object_set_new(msgType,"reqID",json_string(reqId));
            json_object_set_new(msgType,"method",json_string(metName));
            json_object_set_new(msgType,"speakID",json_string(reqId));
            json_object_set_new(msgType,"numSegments",json_integer(1));
            char * jsonStringResponse = json_dumps(root, 0 );
mg_websocket_write(connecion, 1, jsonStringResponse, strlen(jsonStringResponse));
```

which forms this in the variable jsonStringResponse

```
{"response":{"method":"Speak","reqID":"30","speakID":"30","numSegments":"1"}}
```

Now at the client side implementation, this is how it is validated and I am failing to pass this validation.

```
// test the Speak method
it('Speak', function(done) {
    var id = "123";
    var method = "Speak";

    WsTestBase.send({
        "request":
        {
            "method": method,
            "reqID": id,
            "parameters":
            {
                "text" : ttsText
            }
        }
    });

 WsTestBase.validate({
        "method": method,
        "reqID":id,
        "speakID":id,
        "numSegments":1
    },[
        { eventName : 'SpeechEnd', speakID : id }
    ], done);

});
```

Please let me know how do I send the `eventName` that is expected and which is missing in my response body?

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure of what are you trying to do, but WebSockets are asynchronous.

This is how I do tests using WebSockets using [asynchronous unit tests](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/test-asynchronous-methods-using-the-jasmine-runs-and-waitfor-methods.html#fbid=OE3dRRY9K8v):

```
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8006/", "text");

describe("Connects: ", function () {
    var connected = false;
    it("Connected", function () {

        runs(function () {
            ws.onopen = function (event) {
                connected = true;
            };
        });

        waitsFor(function () {
            return connected;
        }, "Error", 1000);

        runs(function () {
            expect(connected).toBe(true);
        });
    });

});

describe("Small Strings: ", function () {
    var result = '';

    it("Must reverse the 'Hi' string", function () {

        ws.onmessage = function (event) {
            result = event.data;
        };

        runs(function () {
            ws.send("Hi");
        });

        waitsFor(function () {
            return result == 'iH';
        }, "Error", 1000);

        runs(function () {
            expect(result).toBe('iH');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The link was helpful. Thank you !! You just got me right. I am implementing the server side of the project. Client, as you mention does a websocket connection and sends me requests as you see. I parse and frame back the response in json form. Now my problem is, sending the eventName that is expected. How do i send it ? It is required in [] brackets in function validate()

Comment: Oh you want to know how to implement the server side?

Comment: yup. i want to send response from server. n yes i am implementing the server side